# How to only return one row per met criteria in Access SQL?

Tags: ms-access

I have data that looks like this

```
CUSTID     POLICY     TYPE   RANDOMTHING   ETC
```

And sometimes there will be multiply rows per CUSTID, with different values for the rest of the fields otherwise. I only want to return one row per CUSTID, taking only the first row's values (ignoring the rest).

I've tried applying First to CUSTID but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried using a `TOP 1` predicate as part of your query?  (I am assuming that you are writing a SQL statement).

Comment: How do I do a "TOP 1"? And yes I can edit the SQL statement

Comment: googled it and I don't think this is what I need. It only returns the very top row of my dataset. I need the "top" row per CUSTID (and in practice my CUSTID is like the second field)

Comment: I missed a subtle point in your question.  Sorry.

Comment: Do you have any other numerical fields besides custid?

Comment: No fields are technically numeric, the ID is alphanumeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM yourTable t1 INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT CUSTID, MIN(POLICY) AS MinOfPOLICY 
        FROM yourTable
        GROUP BY CUSTID
    ) t2 ON t1.CUSTID = t2.CUSTID AND t1.POLICY = t2.MinOfPOLICY
ORDER BY 1
```

In this example, `t1` and `t2` are table aliases. In most cases when constructing a query that references the same table more than once, table aliases are required to disambiguate column references. For example, you can't just say `CUSTID` because it's unclear as to whether you mean `CUSTID` from the first instance of `yourTable`, or from the second instance.

The SQL language allows tables to be given an alias by placing the alias immediately after the table name, so `yourTable t1`  means "`yourTable`, using the alias `t1`". The other alias, `t2`, is the alias for the `GROUP BY` subquery (the one inside the brackets).

Comment: Looks like a good guess to me.  :-)  If that's not what he's after, he should show us sample data and the output he wants from that sample.

Comment: @HansUp [TYPE] was the only other likely candidate for the implicit sort. Sort on RANDOMTHING didn't look like it would be the best choice.... :)

Comment: I don't understand what t1 and t2 here are? Or how to parse "yourTable t1". Say my query name is MyQuery

Comment: Also "Join expression not supported"

Comment: @JohnSmith RE: `t1`, `t2` -- I just updated my answer. RE: "Join expression not supported" -- I just copied my query into the SQL view of an Access query window and it worked fine. If you are having trouble with your query you can edit your question and post it.